# Custom ListView with Multiple Button and with listener but with ambiguity in list Number Click

Tags: android

i have a custom listView in which i have six button on each list item and when i click on the four item it changes the first item in my list i have worked a lot on this problem but i did't get any solution for this if any body know the solution please let me know and thanks for "Your" Consideration Here's My Code of arrayAdapter. all i Wanted to change the color of button when the clicked

my Xml Code for each button and i also added
  android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" with layout

```
  <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_M"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="M" 
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:textColor="#00FF00"
        />
```

My Adapter Code

```
Context context;
LayoutInflater inflater;
ArrayList<String> arr;
ViewHold viewHolder;
Button btn_Monday;
private boolean flagM;
private boolean flagT;
private boolean flagW;
private boolean flagTh;
private boolean flagF;
private boolean flagS;

private ArrayList<ViewHold> holdArray;
public CustomAdapterOfExcercise(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<String>                objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.context=context;
    arr=objects;
    inflater=(LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    flagM=flagT=flagW=flagTh=flagF=flagS=true;
    holdArray=new ArrayList<CustomAdapterOfExcercise.ViewHold>();
}

private static class ViewHold{
    TextView excercise_name;
    ImageButton img_Of_Excercise;
    Button btn_M,btn_T,btn_W,btn_Th,btn_F,btn_Sa,btn_remove;         
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View vi=convertView;
    final int pos=position;
    if(convertView==null){
        vi=inflater.inflate(R.layout.excercise_list_item_view, null);
        viewHolder=new ViewHold(); 
        viewHolder.excercise_name=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.tv_Of_Excersice_Name);
        viewHolder.img_Of_Excercise=(ImageButton)vi.findViewById(R.id.image_Of_Excercise);
        viewHolder.btn_M=(Button)vi.findViewById(R.id.button_M);
        btn_Monday=(Button)vi.findViewById(R.id.button_M);
        viewHolder.btn_T=(Button)vi.findViewById(R.id.button_T);
        viewHolder.btn_W=(Button)vi.findViewById(R.id.button_W);
        viewHolder.btn_Th=(Button)vi.findViewById(R.id.button_Th);
        viewHolder.btn_F=(Button)vi.findViewById(R.id.button_F);
        viewHolder.btn_Sa=(Button)vi.findViewById(R.id.button_Sa);
        viewHolder.btn_remove=(Button)vi.findViewById(R.id.button_Remove);
        vi.setTag(viewHolder);      
        holdArray.add(viewHolder);
        btn_Monday.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(flagM){

                    holdArray.get(pos).btn_M.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);

                    Log.d("Position of List Item "," "+pos);
                    flagM=false;


enter code here


                }else{

                    holdArray.get(pos).btn_M.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                    Log.d("Position of List Item "," "+pos);
                    flagM=true;

                }
            }
        });


        viewHolder.btn_T.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(flagT){

                    holdArray.get(pos).btn_T.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                     Log.d("Position of List Item "," "+pos);
                     flagT=false;

                 }else{

                     holdArray.get(pos).btn_T.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                     Log.d("Position of List Item "," "+pos);
                     flagT=true;

                 }
            }
        });

        viewHolder.btn_W.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 if(flagW){

                     holdArray.get(pos).btn_W.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                       Log.d("Position of List Item "," "+pos);
                       flagW=false;

                 }else{

                     holdArray.get(pos).btn_W.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                     Log.d("Position of List Item "," "+pos);
                     flagW=true;

                 }
            }
        });

        viewHolder.btn_Th.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 if(flagTh){

                     holdArray.get(pos).btn_Th.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                     Log.d("Position of List Item "," "+pos);
                     flagTh=false;

                 }else{

                     holdArray.get(pos).btn_Th.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                     Log.d("Position of List Item "," "+pos);
                     flagTh=true;
                 }
            }
        });

        viewHolder.btn_F.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(flagF){

                    holdArray.get(pos).btn_F.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                    Log.d("Position of List Item "," "+pos);
                    flagF=false;

                }else{

                    holdArray.get(pos).btn_F.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                    Log.d("Position of List Item "," "+pos);
                    flagF=true;
                }
            }
        });


        viewHolder.btn_Sa.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(flagS){          

                    holdArray.get(pos).btn_Sa.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                    Log.d("Position of List Item "," "+pos);
                    flagS=false;

                }else{

                    holdArray.get(pos).btn_Sa.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                    Log.d("Position of List Item "," "+pos);
                    flagS=true;
                }
            }
        });

    }else{
      viewHolder=(ViewHold)vi.getTag();


    }

        viewHolder.excercise_name.setText(arr.get(position));


        viewHolder.btn_remove.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        }); 

    return vi;
}

public void notifyChangeHappen() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    this.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

this is code very easy and short

```
 <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_M"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="M" 
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:textColor="#00FF00"
        android:onClick="btnClick"/>
        />
```

and writer this method in Activity Context

```
public void btnClick(View v) {
//execute codes
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello Gangster i Got the Answer for this:

Every One who is getting this type of problem can get this solution
 however i don't no it is according to std. or not but i fix my problem
  "Wo Hamare Hariyana me Kehte h"
" Aapna kam banta Baad me Gaye Ganta  ;)"

here we Go

```
//i created a  arraylist which is of <ViewHolder> Type
ArrayList<ViewHolder> list_Of_Holder;
//then i created a arraylist of View <View>
ArrayList<View> list_Of_View; 
//On more list Of boolean values 
ArrayList<boolean> position_Of_Item;
//Inflater
 LayoutInflater inflater;
//ArrayList of Data to be Inserted
 ArrayList<String> dataList;
//Context 
 Context context;
//View Holder Class Instance
 ViewHolder viewHolder;
//flag for buttons text color
  boolean falgMonday,flagTuesday;

//Now in the Constructor initialize them 
 ClassConstructor(Context context,int res,ArrayList<String> dataList){
  list_Of_Holder=new ArrayList<ViewHolder>();
  list_Of_View=new ArrayList<View>();
  position_Of_Item=new ArrayList<Boolean>();
  this.dataList=dataList;
  this.context=context;
  //Cross Check this initialization i m not sure abt this service Name
  inflater=(LayoutInflater)context.getSystemServices(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATE_SERVICE);

  //for view Recycle control i take this list and initialize like this
   for(int i=0;i<1000;i++){

        position_Of_Item.add(true);
     }
 }

  private Class ViewHolder{
     //create Instance Variables of ur view here 

  }

  //This is the getView Method for 
 View getView(){

    View vi=convertView;
    final int pos=position;
if(listArray.get(pos)==true){
  vi=inflater.inflate(R.layout.excercise_list_item_view, null);
  viewHolder=new ViewHolder(); 
  viewHolder.excercise_name=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.tv_Of_Excersice_Name);
  viewHolder.img_Of_Excercise=(ImageButton)vi.findViewById(R.id.image_Of_Excercise);
  viewHolder.btn_Monday=(Button)vi.findViewById(R.id.button_M);
  btn_Monday=(Button)vi.findViewById(R.id.button_M);
  viewHolder.btn_Tuesday=(Button)vi.findViewById(R.id.button_T);
  viewHolder.btn_W=(Button)vi.findViewById(R.id.button_W);
  viewHolder.btn_Th=(Button)vi.findViewById(R.id.button_Th);
  viewHolder.btn_F=(Button)vi.findViewById(R.id.button_F);
  viewHolder.btn_Sa=(Button)vi.findViewById(R.id.button_Sa);
  viewHolder.btn_remove=(Button)vi.findViewById(R.id.button_Remove);


  list_Of_Holder.add(viewHolder);

      //Here Add Listener To all the View here like this
     /*I wanted to change alternate color after every click on each button in each list 
       item */
      list_Of_Holder.get(pos).btn_Monday.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(flagMonday){
      list_Of_Holder.get(pos).btn_Monday.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
      flagMonday=false;
    }else{
      list_Of_Holder.get(pos).btn_Monday.setTextColor(Color.RED);
      flagMonday=true;
    }
 }
});
 list_Of_Holder.get(pos).btn_Tuesday.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(flagTuesday){
    list_Of_Holder.get(pos).btn_Tuesday.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
    flagTuesday=false;
    }else{
    list_Of_Holder.get(pos).btn_Tuesday.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    flagTuesday=true;
 }
}
 });

   list_Of_Holder.get(pos).excercise_name.setText(arr.get(pos));
 //Add Listener to ur View Like this here
    vi.setTag(viewHolder);  
list_Of_View.add(vi);
position_Of_Item.set(pos, false);

 } //End of if Condition

 return list_Of_View.get(pos);
```

}

if something Goes Wrong than let me know plz